# prolog undirected graphs lines issue

Tags: prolog

Hi all I am having an issue

I have a graph non directed [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xfcR.png)
[image]

I have listed each node in the form of node(name,[path]).
where a node that has multiple paths is node(name,[pathName,path]). //for however may paths intersect with node.

```
>node(giant,[sizePath]).
>node(large,[sizePath]).
>node(big,[sizePath]).
>node(a0,[numPath,alphabetPath]).
>node(1,[numPath]).
>node(2,[numPath]).
>node(3,[numPath]).
>node(b,[alphabetPath]).
>node(c,[alphabetPath]).
>node(d,[alphabetPath]).
```

I have then written a rule stating

```
samePath(Node1,Node2,PathName):-node(Node1,PathName),node(Node,1PathName).
```

> if I use values `samePath(2,3,PathName)` I get the output
>
> ```
> true; 
> numLine.
> ```
>
> however if I use the values `samePth(A0,1,PathName)` I should get
>
> ```
> true;
> numLine.
> ```
>
> however I get
>
> ```
> true;
> fail.
> ```

as it will not list only the element that matches in both lists

Comment: You need to put the entire program on display!

Comment: I did but here it is again

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing lists rather than elements of lists - to get this working you should modify samePath to read

```
samePath(Node1,Node2,PathName) :-
    node(Node1,Paths1),
    node(Node2,Paths2),
    member(PathName,Paths1),
    member(PathName,Paths2).
```

This will unify PathName with any paths in both lists.